# NSIS installer: Calling an MSI file without launching a separte installer

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

Is it possible to write NSIS script that it calls my MSI file without launching the installer separately?

Answer (score 2):

You still need to launch the process but you don't have to show anything. Try:

```
msiexec /i yourinstaller.msi /qn
```

The `/qn` option won't show a user interface.